# how to tell FlowType to ignore some json requires?

Tags: flowtype

I have this kind of code in a ./src folder:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var config = require("../config.json")
```

when run flow, it has this error:

```
var config = require("../config.json")
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../config.json. Required module not found
```

to me, that's a valid statement because the final version will be in a folder with that config.json, is there a way to instruct flowtype not checking this type of error?

Thanks

Comment: "to me, that's a valid statement because the final version will be in a folder with that config.json". The file isn't always there?

Answer (score 0):

You could make flow ignore all json files by adding the following to your `.flowconfig`:

```
[ignore]
.*\.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the json file to be checked as well, you could use [`module.name_mapper`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string) to map to the location of your json file. Flow automatically checks `require`d json files.

It would looks something like:

```
module.name_mapper='^\(.*\)\.json$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/path/to/json/files'
```